# What is the reason for the leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

How to fix memory leak in this code?
What is the reason for the leak?

```
var theItem = null;
var replaceItem = function() {
    var priorItem = theItem;
    var writeToLog = function() {
        if (priorItem) {
            console.log("hi");
        }
    };
    theItem = {
        longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
        someMethod: function() {
            console.log(someMessage);
        }
    };
};
setInterval(replaceItem, 1000);
```

Comment: If you accept answer click on its left side on gray "check" button. You can also vote up on answer by clicking on gray triangle near.

Comment: Where did you find this code? It doesn't look like you wrote it yourself. Please link the source.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in every time you call `replaceItem` you increase chain of object because that function inside has pointer to `priorItem` which pointer to result of previous function invocation which was "saved" in `theItem` global variable (outside function). So n'th function invocation has pointer to result of (n-1)'th function invocation - and your create chain of pointers in that way - an JS garbage collector don't clean that chain (unless you set null to it's beginning - global `theItem`, and stop call function).

The `theItem` object contains `someMethod` which contains in scope previous value of `theItem` (which contains further previous value... and so on...).

This will be more visible in [this modified code](https://jsfiddle.net/w2zsaeg7/) - whe we debug it in chrome:

[image]

I don't know what is your purpose but just break that chain by for example remove line `var priorItem = theItem;` inside `replaceItem` function body (and also to save functionality change `if (priorItem) {` to `if (theItem) {`).

Comment: "*that function inside has pointer to `priorItem`*" - uh, only `writeToLog` closes over `priorItem`, and it isn't used in the object. The object's `someMethod` only closes over `someMessage` (which is not declared anywhere...)?